# Delete data that are associated with #N/A

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following data

```
A B   C   D   E

1  test abc abc abc #N/A

2

3
```

I want to delete the 3 abc along with the #N/A but I can't delete the entire row as it may have data that are not to be deleted. The range are not fixed too.

I thought of the following code but it just replaces the #N/A with ""

```
Cells.Replace "#N/A", "", xlWhole
```

Do share with me if you have any tips on it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the criteria to delete cells? delete from column `B` until find `#N/A`? What you mean by delete: clear contents or shift cells left?

Comment: The criteria is as long as there is a #N/A, the data on the previous 4 columns on the same row before #N/A have to be deleted/Clear content

Comment: Where do you want to search `#N/A`? Column E or everywhere?

Comment: #N/A can be found at Column T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own answer hits the point, but need some correction and tuning:

```
Sub DeleteNA()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Intersect(ActiveSheet.Columns("T"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Cells
        If VarType(c.Value) = vbError And c.Text = "#N/A" Then c.Offset(, -4).Resize(, 5).ClearContents
    Next
End Sub
```

If this still taking long time, consider using `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

EDIT: Correction for clearing cell and 4 cells at right (instead of 3)

Comment: can i check with you, the command c.Offset(, -3) what does it do? I wasn't able to remove adddition columns if it go beyond 3. The codes work just fine

Comment: `Range.Offset([rows], [columns])` returns a new range shifted by a number of rows and/or columns specified. `c.Offset(, -3)` mean cells 3 columns right from cell `c`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and found a way after modifying some of the codes I found online,

```
Sub DeleteNA()
Dim r As Long
Dim iCol As Long

    For iCol = 1 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For r = Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
             If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cells(r, iCol)) Then

             Cells(r, iCol - 4) = ""
             Cells(r, iCol - 3) = ""
             Cells(r, iCol - 2) = ""
             Cells(r, iCol - 1) = ""
             Cells(r, iCol) = ""

             End If
        Next r
    Next iCol
    End Sub
```

It looks long and may take a long time when the data gets many..